# Meaning of the phrase "Lean in"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

There's a book entitled [Lean In: Women, Work, and the Will to Lead](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385349947).

It's not clear what exactly phrasal verb **Lean in** in it's title means. Does its meaning differ from the meaning of the verb **to lean** in the context of the book's name?

Comment: The intention is not clear from the title. It may become clear from reading the book, and/or this will be merely a matter of opinion. Voting to close as interpretation of literature and/or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of literature and/or primarily opinion-based

Comment: From the context, it sounds *similar* to "put your shoulder to the wheel" ... http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+shoulder+to+the+wheel

Comment: @TrevorD, The question is not asking for an interpretation of literature, it's requesting the meaning of an expression.

Comment: @KristinaLopez It's requesting the meaning of an expression, *specifically as used in the title*. We can't interpret the title without knowing the content of the book. In any event, *if* it's simply asking for the meaning of "lean in" as "an expression", it's GR, as demonstrated by your answer.

Comment: @TrevorD, Actually, my answer is not GR and its a very relevent question because the original meaning has been adapted by a women's movement, of sorts, to a specific, related meaning.  I 'm just saying we shouldn't be so quick to close something in the absence of *personal* knowledge. :-)

Comment: It's not obvious that it's necessary to realise that the colon is not introducing an explanation (Herpetology: the study of snakes), breakdown (States of matter: solids, liquids and gases), or subsetting (Marine fish: the rays) of the preceding expression - or list of complements (My travels in: The US, the UK, and Siberia) - but merely a subtitle (cf 'The Hobbit, or There and Back Again').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is about women needing to move out of their comfort zone and work harder to break into senior management positions traditionally held by men.

> From the Free Dictionary:
>
> **"lean in (to something)"**
>
> to incline or press into something. You have to lean into the wind
> when you walk or you will be blown over. As you walk into the wind,
> lean in a little bit. The north wall of the barn leans in a little. Is
> it going to fall? See also: lean

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.)