# What does “leaning in” mean as basic qualifications of women in the pursuit of positions in the workplace?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

New York Times’ article written by Scott Schieman,  et al under the headline, “When Leaning in doesn’t pay off” starts with the following sentence;
http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/11/opinion/sunday/when-leaning-in-doesnt-pay-off.html?hp

> “Why do women not have as many leadership roles in the workplace as
>   men do? Some have pointed to internal barriers, suggesting that the
>   problem is partly attributable to something about women themselves,
>   they are not “ambitious enough” at work, or are deeply committed to
>   work but too hesitant to climb leadership ladders in organizations. -
>   - - Sheryl Sandberg, in her now famous phrase, would have women “**lean in**,” to be more assertive at work and not let biases keep
>   them from pushing forward. By leaning in, women would obtain more
>   authority.
>
> To understand the claims embedded in the “**lean in**” hypothesis, we
>   need to know why, when or how women decide to pursue positions of
>   authority in the workplace."

As I haven’t read Sheryl Sandberg’s book, I don’t know what she means by “lean in.”

Unfortunately none of Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam Webster Dictionary includes “lean in” as an idiom, though all of them carry “lean on sb. / stg.”

What does “lean in” means? Does it mean stronger devotion to the work? In what instances is 'lean in' used as an idiom? Is “lean in” a neologism with specific implications /purposes invented by Sheryl Sandberg?

By the way:

Sheryl Sandberg’s ‘Lean In” is translated into Japanese by Yuko Kawamoto et al, published by Nihon Keizai Press, one of Japan’s leading newspapers known by the financial term, 'Nikkei Index' and a publisher recently, and widely read by Japanese businesswomen and men. It's becoming a best-seller.

The title and the word, ‘Lean In’ of the Japanese version are translated as “Make a step forward.” However, I wonder if “Make a step forward” exactly fits what Sandberg intends to convey and what you perceive with this word.

To me "lean in" and "make a step forword"- there's the axiom in Zen, 'Make a stepfoward at the end of a cliff to get Satori (spiritual enlightment) - sound different as a physical action or posture, setting aside the state and level of mind.

Comment: You quoted it right there: “lean in,” to be more assertive at work and not let biases keep them from pushing forward.  The scare quotes make me think this is a new term, invented by Sheryl Sandberg to describe this particular behavior.

Comment: I provided a definition of that expression in this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122181/meaning-of-the-phrase-lean-in

Comment: There used to be scores of books titled “Self-asertion” and Assertiveness trainings in the market when I was still young scores of years ago (1970s-80s). Did Sheryl Sandberg simply touch up classic “Be assertive” mantra, or did she add to new insight to women’s self-assertion?

Comment: 'to lean in' is not an existing phrasal verb or even a set phrase, but is a reasonable, recognizable meaning that evokes, in the face of strong push back, to try harder. Actually, now that I think of it, this is very natural to use for heavy physical labor, to try extra hard, putting extra weight to psh something very heavy, put your weight behind it. The title is an easy metaphor for 'dont just let things happen, try harder'.

Comment: Reading comments of KitFaox and yours, Japanese word,のめり込む (nomerikomu) meaning ‘go into (one’s work) heart and soul / devote oneself to stg” came up top of my mind as its translation. We use this expression to the person who is fully immersed in any object such as business, studies, and shemes.

Comment: TrevorD. Yes. It may duplicate. I didn’t know that there was a question on this word before. But as you pointed out in his question, the question of Serguis was concerned with the interpretation of a book title without context (for which I feel really sorry for his getting 4 close votes) at that time. And you said “It's requesting the meaning of an expression, specifically as used in the title. We can't interpret the title without knowing the content of the book” in your comment to Serguis.

Comment: Cont. Now that the New York Times, which is read worldwide uses the word without quotation marks in the headline of their article which was shown as the feature article in their home page viewed by millions of web users around the world, it’s not the subject on the one-off title of a Sheryl Sandberg’s book. I believe it’s worth for readdressing to make sure of the meaning and impact of the word.

Comment: Yoichi, it is difficult to measure impact if the word has not been supported for very long after the initial use in The New York Times and, if anything, Trevor's duplicate, for what is worth, clarifies its meaning enough.

Comment: Carlo_R. I don’t feel like arguing currency of the usage of “Lean in” in Sandberg’s way and whether it is one-off phrase or not. Frank H. informed me in his answer that Sandberg used this word in a commencement speech at Barnard College in May 2011 in contrast to your observation, “the word has not been supported for very long after the initial use in The New York Times.” I was simply drawn to the phrase as it was introduced as ‘in her “now famous” phrase not as the first person’s view, but by three co-writers of Scott Schieman, Markus Schatter and Mitchell Mclvor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In body language, leaning forward (in) is generally understood to convey interest and engagement whereas leaning back conveys detachment and lack of interest. Sheryl Sandberg uses the term "Lean in" to describe how women act/react in a business or boardroom scenario where a group of people are sitting around a table and decisions are being made. In such a scenario, she suggests, women turn down opportunities in anticipation of having a family one day.

She mentioned this in a [commencement speech at Barnard College](http://barnard.edu/headlines/transcript-and-video-speech-sheryl-sandberg-chief-operating-officer-facebook) in May 2011:

> These women don’t even have relationships, and already they’re finding balance, balance for responsibilities they don’t yet have.  And from that moment, they start quietly **leaning back**... So, my heartfelt message to all of you is, and start thinking
>   about this now, do not leave before you leave.  Do not lean back; **lean in.**

Comment: I don't understand how "lean in" ever came to be used to describe the pursuit of promotion at work. To me, the phrase has certainly got a meaning - most typically, to lean in through a doorway or window to see something _while remaining on the outside_  . Moreover, to lean is a passive, drooping stance with little or no implication of the energy and activity needed to get ahead at work.
I note that many people ask what the phrase means.